# visual studioでファイル転送機能を実装したい。

Tags: c++, ftp

visual studioでftpによるWindows内のファイルをLinuxマシン上に転送する機能をc++で実装したいのですが、調べて見つけたサイトを参考にしても、ヘッダファイルがインクルードできなかったり、これでできるのかわからないものがあります(そもそもc++を使って作成しているものが少ないです)。

サイトを記載しますので、ご助言いただけますでしょうか。

https://www.straightapps.com/win/dev/ftp-connection.html

https://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/ftp/vc/

Comment: 完全ではないかもしれませんが、自分で作るならこの辺の記事が参考になるかも。[FTPS通信を行うソースコード、もしくはライブラリかAPIを探しています。](https://teratail.com/questions/360705), [embeddedmz/ftpclient-cpp](https://github.com/embeddedmz/ftpclient-cpp), [FTP not supported in vcpkg curl port?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53710708/9014308) あとは自分で作る必要があるのか、既に有るプログラムを呼び出す方法で代替出来るか？ といったことを考えた方が良いかもしれません。[VBAでftp.exeを簡単に使うサンプル【Shell関数】](https://www.tekizai.net/entry/vba_shell_ftp)

Comment: MFCアプリケーションなのでしょうか？ ヘッダをインクルードできないというのは、ftp以前にMFCアプリケーションの事前条件を満たせていないような気がします。逆にMFCアプリケーションでないなら、そのライブラリは使えません。

Comment: ヘッダがインクルード出来ないというレベルだと、この質問以前の問題だと思うので回答貰っても検証のしようがないのでは… 1から10まで全部教えて欲しいということであれば、只の丸投げなのでメンターでも雇うか外注した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

いきなりプログラムを自作するってのは下策中の下策で、転送するだけなら既にあるものを使うほうが適切っス。なんたって開発期間０開発費用０なんだから。なのでどんな転送手段が適切であるのかは案件次第。

- その PC ２台は隣接しているの、遠隔地にあるの？
- 転送容量はいくら（数キロバイト？　数エクサバイト？）
- 転送にかかってよい時間はどの程度（数秒で終わってほしい / 一晩かかってよい）
- セキュリティ的考察は必要？

などなどの必要事項が判断できるのは質問者氏だけです。

助言でよいという質問なので、オイラからの助言は「作るな」っス。あえて付け加えるなら、「案件分析が済むまでは自分の勝手な思い込みで必要のないものを作るな」でしょう。